# Not able to convert hashtable to array and attach it to pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert hashtable to array and to attach it to pscustomobject - and convert it to json after.

My code looks like this:

```
     foreach ($lz in $lzs) {
        # Read parameters from the file
        $params = Get-Content -Raw -Path $PARAMETERS | ConvertFrom-Json
        # Update parameters as needed
        $params.parameters.parPeeredVnetSubscriptionId.value = $lz.subscriptionId

        foreach ($subnet in $subnetsArray) {
          if ($subnet.spokeNetworkName -eq $landingZone.parSpokeNetworkName) {
            $subnetHashtable = @{
              name = $subnet.name
            }

            $params.parameters.parSubnets.value += [pscustomobject] $subnetHashtable
            Write-Host $params.parameters.parSubnets.value # output @{name=sub-001-dev}
          }
        }

        $updatedParamsJson = $params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
        Write-Host $updatedParamsJson

        $updatedParamsJson = $updatedParamsJson.Replace('"', '\"')
        az deployment mg what-if --name $NAME --location $LOCATION --management-group-id $mgid --template-file $TEMPLATEFILE --parameters "$updatedParamsJson"
     }
```

I am getting this output:

> "parSubnets": {
> "value": [
> "@{name=sub-001-dev}"
> ]
> }

What I want to achieve is to have it in this form, so I can use that json file as parameter for whatif/deployment

> "parSubnets": {
> "value": [
> {
> "name":"sub-001-dev",
> "delegation":[
> "id":"001",
> "name":"test"
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

Comment: What does `$params.parameters.parSubnets.value.GetType()` output? `Write-Host` will coerce the object to a string, remove it here: `Write-Host $params.parameters.parSubnets.value` and check if the output is what you expect

Comment: It looks like you need to increase the depth in your `ConvertTo-Json` call.

Comment: `[array]$params.parameters.parSubnets.value += [pscustomobject] $subnetHashtable`, you should initialize an array. As an aside: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You were right. It was the depth of the ConvertTo-Json that was the problem